# how to show a hotels opening or closing timings based upon working hours

Tags: php, slim, strtotime

in my database table i have stored start_at and end_at timings of hotels

---

> Here is my  slim api php code

```
`  $st_time  = strtotime('Start_at');
  $end_time = strtotime('end_at');
  $stmt->execute();
  $data=$stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $cur_time= time();
  if($st_time < $cur_time && $end_time > $cur_time)
  {
  echo $res='open ';
  }
 else
 {
 echo $res='Close';
 }
```

`

Comment: `strtotime('Start_at')` start at what? You need to provide a date as an argument.

Comment: i took my databse table fields strt_at =  07:30:00 and end_at =22:30:00

Comment: In this code, you're not doing that. Plus you haven't even fetched the values when you assign them.

Comment: may i use foreach loop to show the timings of hotels

Answer (score 0):

You can do string comparisons and it will work in PHP. This is what will help you in the right direction...

```
  $st_time  = '07:30:00';
  $end_time = '22:30:00';
  $cur_time = date('H:i:s');
  if($st_time < $cur_time && $end_time > $cur_time){
    echo 'Open';
  } else {
    echo 'Close';
  }
```